# Get access to parent class

Tags: c#, oop

I'm fighting with some classes or better objects taht are nested in a "main object".

Example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string MothersName { get; set; }
    public Child child = new Child(){ ChildsName = "Child1"; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string ChildsName{ get; set; }
    .... Parent MothersName = "LovelyOne";
}
```

So is there any way to change the mothers name from the child-object?

Comment: The child needs to have a reference to the parent (in the same way that `Parent` has `Child`).

Comment: what does mean change the mothers name from the child? You want change the reference of mothersName in the child and in the parent at same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child needs to have a reference to the parent class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string MothersName { get; set; }
    public Child child;

    public Parent()
    {
       child = new Child("Child1", this);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public string ChildsName { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; }

    public Child(string childsName, Parent parent)
    {
        this.ChildsName = childsName;
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

`myChild.Parent.MothersName = "LovelyOne";` works now inside of Child.

Comment: Actually `myChild.Parent.MothersName = "LovelyOne";` will not work. There is no public property called Parent, but I guess OP gets the point.

Comment: @Michael: Good point. Since I don't know the OP's use case, I have just changed it to a public property.